# SSH key-type, rsa, dsa, ecdsa, are there easy answers for which to choose when?

Tags: ssh, key-generation

As someone who knows little about cryptography, I wonder about the choice I make when creating ssh-keys.

`ssh-keygen -t type`, where type is either of dsa,rsa and ecdsa.

Googling can give *some* information about differences between the types, but not anything conclusive. So my question is, are there any "easy" answers for developers/system administrators with little cryptography knowledge, when to choose which key type?

I'm hoping for an answer in the style of "Use DSA for X and Y, RSA for Z, and ECDSA for everything else", but I also realise it's quite possible such simple answers are not available.

Comment: Only RSA is an encryption algorithm. Both DSA and ECDSA are used for digital signing - the latter being an Elliptic Curve implementation of DSA (Digital Signature Algorithm). Elliptic curve cryptography is able to provide the same security level as RSA with a smaller key and is a "lighter calculation" workload-wise.

So, use RSA for encryption, DSA for signing and ECDSA for signing on mobile devices.

Comment: related: [ECDSA vs ECDH vs Ed25519 vs Curve25519](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/50878/ecdsa-vs-ecdh-vs-ed25519-vs-curve25519)

Comment: @HenningKlevjer: Although RSA can do both encryption and signing, SSH2 uses it only for signing.

Comment: FYI If you want to determine type of an existing key: `ssh-keygen -l -f key_file`

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys#Choosing_the_authentication_key_type

Answer (score 145, accepted):

In practice, a RSA key will work everywhere. ECDSA support is newer, so some old client or server may have trouble with ECDSA keys.  A DSA key used to work everywhere, as per the SSH standard ([RFC 4251](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4251) and subsequent), but this changed recently: OpenSSH 7.0 and higher no longer accept DSA keys by default.

ECDSA is computationally lighter, but you'll need a really small client or server (say 50 MHz embedded ARM processor) to notice the difference.

*Right now*, there is no security-related reason to prefer one type over any other, assuming large enough keys (2048 bits for RSA or DSA, 256 bits for ECDSA); key size is specified with the `-b` parameter. However, some `ssh-keygen` versions may reject DSA keys of size other than 1024 bits, which is currently unbroken, but arguably not as robust as could be wished for. So, if you indulge in some slight paranoia, you might prefer RSA.

To sum up, do `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048` and you will be happy.

Comment: DSA always makes me uneasy because a signature generated with a broken RNG can compromise the key. RSA keys have an easier to understand and less worrisome failure mode: generating a key with a broken RNG compromises the key, running a session with a broken RNG compromises the session at most.

Comment: @Thomas I'm curious, since this question was posted before the Snowden affair. Has anything recently come to light that would affect this answer?

Comment: No. In fact, everything that was revealed in that affair only confirms what was already known, i.e. that when big governmental agencies spy on people, then don't do it by trying to break cryptography upfront; they rather work around it. In the SSH case, they would collect metadata (_this_ client machine connects to _that_ server) that is not protected by the SSH protocol, regardless of the server key algorithm or size.

Comment: *"As per the SSH standard (RFC 4251 and subsequent), a DSA key will work everywhere"* - In practice, that is no longer true. OpenSSH silently disabled DSA somewhere around 7.0 or 7.1.

Comment: As far as I have understood, this answer is no longer true. OpenSSH 7.0 deprecated ssh-dsa keys, as far as I understand due to security concertns. See http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-announce/2015-August/000122.html

Comment: What is the reasoning behind saying `2048` is enough? And, is there an estimate for how long it will be enough? Given Moore's Law and (even though I don't know if I say something stupid here) quantum computing? I am far off from being a security expert, and I am curious where this value (2048) comes from.

Comment: When you say RSA will work everywhere -- this is going to come off really pedantic, but it doesn't. It doesn't work places that don't support encryption keys, and in some places where the keys are technically supported, like Github,  they often fail to work. A better formulation would be "Out of the available encryption systems, RSA is most likely to be supported." Or something like that. I'm sure you can word it more succinctly.

Comment: @user50849  >.. posted before the Snowden affair. Has anything recently come to light ... Actually yes Snowden did revel a lot about ssh specifically what was compromised and what was not. Some of this was specifically spelled out and some was ascertained from the author who published the interview.

Comment: Go with 4096. More is overkill. If you use ssh a lot, you can still set up multiplexing in your ssh client, in case the waiting time bothers you.

Comment: Correction on "how gov't spies on people": Sometimes they do attack the crypto. https://weakdh.org/ mentions that one NSA attack on VPNs might use their disclosed vulnerability. So don't get complacent. :-P

Comment: This is rather outdated nowadays. Actually, if we’d reasonably look at processing powers, even 16384 would not be enough for RSA. Plus, RSA had a really bad name since the whole NSA debacle with built-in backdoors e.g. in the random number handling.
Thankfully, we have `ed29919` now, which was specifically created because both ecdsa and rsa were not trustworthy enough anymore for anyone but the most black-eyed blind followers, and I’d recommend using that nowadays.

Comment: @Evi1M4chine The "NSA backdoor in RSA" was a backdoor in a random-number-generator by RSA Corporation, wasn't it? Nothing to do with the algorithm also called RSA.

Comment: @exhuma 2048 should be enough simply because we do not yet know how to break keys of that size. It would take tens of millions of dollars to break a 1024-bit key, and 2048 is significantly larger. The best algorithm to crack RSA, called GNFS, is not fast enough to break it. And Moore's law only applies to an increase in computing power (well, transistors), but what would be needed to break RSA 2048 would be a breakthrough in factoring algorithms. And a fully capable quantum computer would break RSA of _any_ (realistic) size. Only newer post-quantum algorithms (e.g. R-LWE) are safe from that.

Answer (score 27):

As gilles says DSA is risky because if you make signatures (and using your key with a ssh client to log in is effectively making signatures) on a box with a bad RNG your key can be compromised. AIUI this made Debian basically [abandon DSA](https://lists.debian.org/debian-infrastructure-announce/2008/05/msg00003.html) for keys used on their infrastructure in light of the Debian OpenSSL random number generator fiasco.

http://meyering.net/nuke-your-DSA-keys/

ECDSA is relatively new, from some quick searching it seems it was introduced in 5.7. Afaict most of these systems are out of support and should probably be migrated but we all know that doesn't happen somtimes. For example, Debian squeeze and ubuntu lucid. ECDSA has advantages in that a key can be much smaller than a RSA or DSA key for the same level of (presumed) security. Unfortunately it shares the disadvantage of DSA of being sensitive to bad random number generators. There are also concerns that the elliptic curves traditionally used may have been backdoored.

ED25519 is an even newer option, introduced by openssh 6.5. It is a variant of the ECDSA algorithm but it solves the random number generator problem and uses a "nothing up my sleeve" curve. It will probably be the best option in the long term but right now there are still supported systems out there that don't have sufficiently new openssh.

So IMO that makes RSA (with a 2048 or 4096 bit key depending on how paranoid you are) still the most reasonable choice for general use.

Edit: update to current situation as of March 2017.

Comment: ECDSA has the same weakness as DSA in this respect. And in OpenSSH it's doubly fishy because OpenSSH only implements NIST curves that are suspected to be backdoored by the NSA. More info here: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/46781/15087

Comment: One mitigation for creating signatures without a good source of randomness is RFC 6979 [Deterministic Usage of the Digital Signature Algorithm (DSA) and
           Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)]. I don't know if OpenSSH uses that though.

Answer (score 11):

Use RSA.  Not for security reasons, but for compatibility reasons.

I don't recommend using DSA keys.  As of OpenSSH 7.0, SSH no longer supports DSA keys by default.  As the [release notes for OpenSSH 7.0 say](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.0), "Support for ssh-dss host and user keys is disabled by default at run-time".  Therefore, using DSA keys (ssh-dss) is just going to cause headaches.

ECDSA keys could be better, but sadly, ECDSA keys can also cause compatibility headaches on some platforms.  On Fedora, gnome-keyring-daemon doesn't automatically pick up ECDSA SSH keys, so you won't be automatically prompted for a password to unlock your SSH key when you try to use it on Fedora.

RSA keys are completely free of these compatibility headaches.  They're the most widely used, and so seem to be the best supported.  Therefore, I recommend you generate RSA keys, to save yourself from annoyances later down the road.

---

As an editorial note, OpenSSH's decision to disable DSA support is a bit puzzling: 1024-bit DSA keys have [approximately the same security](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29267/971) as 1024-bit RSA keys, so it's not clear why OpenSSH disabled support for 1024-bit DSA keys but retain support for 1024-bit RSA keys.  (OpenSSH still supports RSA; it has a special check to disable RSA keys that are 768 bits or shorter, but for DSA, it just disables all DSA keys, regardless of length.)  Also, OpenSSH used to support DSA keys that are longer than 1024 bits in length; it's not clear why support for them has been disabled.  Oh well, so it goes.

Comment: The decision to disable DSA support isn't puzzling.  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5096/rsa-vs-dsa-for-ssh-authentication-keys

Comment: @Cliff the link doesn't support your assertion that it's not puzzling.

Answer (score 10):

DSA and ECDSA have fixed length keys, and they are US government standards meaning that they know more about the standards than the general public. RSA is better known and you can generate longer keys with it (default is 2048 as opposed to DSA's 1024 bit fixed length), so it is (arguably) better to use.

Comment: According to the ssh-keygen man page, you have three choices for ECDSA key lengths:     For ECDSA keys, the -b flag determines the key length by selecting from one of three elliptic curve sizes: 256, 384 or 521 bits.  Attempting to use bit lengths other than these three values for ECDSA keys will fail.

Comment: @jfmercer 521 or 512?

Comment: @Anonymouse it's really 521.  See also http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/how-strong-is-the-ecdsa-algorithm

Comment: @Anonymouse See [Why do the elliptic curves recommended by NIST use 521 bits rather than 512?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6219/why-do-the-elliptic-curves-recommended-by-nist-use-521-bits-rather-than-512). In short, P521 uses this prime because 2^521-1 is a mersenne prime.

Comment: `ssh-keygen` can generate only 1024 for DSA, but can use 2048 genereated by OpenSSL (which also had better PBE until OpenSSH's 'new' format).

Comment: (For completeness) but although OpenSSH can use DSA-2048 (or even 3072), it uses them [_with_ SHA1 because the protocol says so](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15051/why-does-openssh-use-only-sha1-for-signing-and-verifying-of-digital-signatures). Although OpenSSH before 7.2 in 2013 also used RSA (of any size) only with SHA1.