# Does SSH support DSA with 2048 bit keys?

Tags: ssh, openssh, dsa

In FIPS 186-1 and 186-2 L could be any number between 512 and 1024 (inclusive) that was a multiple of 64. N was fixed at 160.

FIPS 186-3 changed it so that L and N could be any combination of the following:

- L = 1024, N = 160
- L = 2048, N = 224
- L = 2048, N = 256
- L = 3072, N = 256

[RFC 4253 (SSH Transport Layer Protocol)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#page-15) says the following:

```
   The resulting signature is encoded as follows:

      string    "ssh-dss"
      string    dss_signature_blob

   The value for 'dss_signature_blob' is encoded as a string containing
   r, followed by s (which are 160-bit integers, without lengths or
   padding, unsigned, and in network byte order).
```

So I take it this means SSH does not support 2048-bit DSA? Are there no RFCs that add support for them? No vendor extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the *hash*: Crossdupe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15051/why-does-openssh-use-only-sha1-for-signing-and-verifying-of-digital-signatures and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39983/which-hash-function-is-used-for-signatures-ssh-rsa-and-ssh-dss
but probably better here.

[A recent answer there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/41206/12642) links to https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2 (of 2016-02-28) which refers to now-expired https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-rsa-dsa-sha2-256-03 which despite the name only upgrades RSA to SHA2, with section 6 explaining that DSA was dropped, as does its still-draft replacement https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-curdle-rsa-sha2-02 .

You can easily confirm no other RFC has changed this in [the IANA registry for SSH](http://www.iana.org/assignments/ssh-parameters/ssh-parameters.xhtml#ssh-parameters-19).

And OpenSSH since 7.0 has deprecated and disabled by default (all) DSA. There were numerous Qs here and related stacks late last year about this e.g.:
[Why OpenSSH deprecated DSA keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112802/why-openssh-deprecated-dsa-keys)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247612/ssh-keeps-skipping-my-pubkey
https://superuser.com/questions/962918/pubkeyacceptedkeytypes-and-ssh-dsa-key-type
So they aren't likely to implement improvements to DSA, and anyone else who pushes something incompatible with OpenSSH usually finds it unused.

"Sorry, Charlie."

FWIW although FIPS 186-3 up *encourages* you to use a hash matching the DSA subgroup size (i.e. N) it doesn't actually require it. OpenSSH `ssh-keygen` won't *generate* a DSA key bigger than 1024, but if you generate such a key by other means (such as OpenSSL 1.0.0 up as of 2010, or Java 8 up as of 2014) OpenSSH `ssh` and `sshd` will *use* it (in 7.0 up once you undo the default disabling). But they use it with SHA1 as per the RFC, which basically discards the security benefit the new 186-3 sizes are intended to provide. (Accept no substitutes. OpenSSL 0.9.8 could generate a DSA key with then-nonstandard N=2048 or 3072 -- but still L=160.)