# What does the letter in an OpenPGP key's bits definition (like 4096D) denote?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, pgp, gnupg

I noticed that when looking at OpenPGP keys on a key server, the key's bits definition is usually followed by a letter, as in "4096**D**" for example. However, there are also keys with other letters than D, for example [here](https://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?search=edgar+smith&op=index) are two keys with "D" and one with "R". There are also keys postfixed with a "g" , as seen [here](https://sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=0x0B7F8B60E3EDFAE3). What does that letter mean and how can I find out what is correct for my own key without uploading it to a keyserver?

I'm using GnuPG/MacGPG2 v2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indicates whether the key is DSA or RSA.  You can read more about the differences between the two [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5096/rsa-vs-dsa-for-ssh-authentication-keys).

You can determine which type your key is using `gpg --list-keys` at the CLI.  I'm not sure what GUI you'd use on a Mac so I can't speak to that.

```
C:\>gpg --list-keys
--------------------------------
pub   4096R/2C55AF0B 2014-10-28 [expires: 2017-10-27]
uid                  Gowen Fawr (gowenfawr) <gowenfawr@example.com>
sub   4096R/6ADD2CE0 2014-10-28 [expires: 2017-10-27]
```

Comment: That's it - thanks four your answer. I used `gpg --list-keys` and found that my key is RSA.